# Xamarin.forms not listed in add new item

Tags: xamarin.forms, new-item

I would like to add a "ContentView" (for making an equivalent to "User Control" in Win Form) in my Xamarin Project (VS2019) but as I try to "Add new Item" I have no templates for Xamarin.Forms.
I have installed all necessary packages and extensions.

Do I miss something? or do I make any mistake?

Thank you all for your support

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are trying to add some item to your Android project. Go to the shared project and retry. You should see ContentView, ContentPage ... options

Answer (score 1):

I think you have created a `Xamarin.Android` project. You need create is a Xamarin.Forms project to add a `ContentView`. The structure of `Xamarin.Forms` project is this:

[image]

So you must add a ContentView to the marked .Net Standard project.

Answer (score 0):

What you created is a [Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android/hello-android-quickstart?pivots=windows#create-the-project) not a [Xamarin.forms Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows). There are detailed explanations in the document and you can check  about how to create those projects.

[ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview) is a control in Xamarin.forms, so you should create a Xamarin.forms project and add it there.